# How to fix this npm "code 1" error installing electron

Tags: electron

While installing electron using this command:

```
npm install electron --save-dev
```

I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ducpm34\Desktop\04_01_2022\electron-app\node_modules\electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! RequestError: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ducpm34\Desktop\04_01_2022\electron-app\node_modules\got\source\request-as-event-emitter.js:178:14)
npm ERR!     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:402:35)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.origin.emit (C:\Users\ducpm34\Desktop\04_01_2022\electron-app\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer\source\index.js:37:11)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ducpm34\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-04T07_39_31_143Z-debug.log
```

How do I fix the `RequestError: self signed certificate in certificate chain` error?

Comment: please, see: [troubleshooting](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/tutorial/installation.md#troubleshooting) also add a content of the `C:\Users\ducpm34\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-01-04T07_39_31_143Z-debug.log` file to your question

Answer (score 3):

To add info in Gokul S' answer, I find useful to specify how to change this variable if you are on a Windows system:

- PowerShell:

  ```
    $env:NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
  ```
- CMD

  ```
    set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Use this command $export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 ,and thank me later!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for this! I was struggling a lot with this :-D

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled nodejs and before npm install used the command $export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 ,